# Almost everywhere analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose we have a measure space $\Omega$ and a function $m\in L^\infty(\Omega,\mathcal{B}(E))$, that is invertible for almost all $\theta\in\Omega$ Further assume, that we have an other function $G$ defined in a complex neighbourhood of $\Omega$, that is analytic and coincides with $m$ on $\Omega$. Is it now possible to deduce that $m$ is everywhere invertible?

Comment: Maybe I'm confused about a hypothesis, but why can't you just take an analytic function with a single isolated zero, e.g. $m(z)=z$ on the disk.

Comment: Is $G$ supposed to be invertible everywhere? Otherwise, I think Matt's example is good enough. You never mention what is special about $G$.